# Methods for assessing convergence of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k a_k$ when $a_k$ is complicated

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Think of the problem of convergence of  the series
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k a_k$$
Is it possible to consider the convergence of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k b_k$ if $\lim \limits_{k\rightarrow\infty } \dfrac{a_k}{b_k}=$ limited and non-zero?

If not, is there any theorem that helps to facilitate the analysis of convergence when $a_k$ is a complicated function of $k$?

Comment: Are there any hypotheses at all for the $a_k$? Because otherwise, you're basically asking if there are theorems that help facilitate the analysis of convergence of any series. For without any hypotheses, the same theorems should also work for $a_k' = (-1)^k a_k$, and so you're considering $\sum a_k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following I will assume that $a_n\ge0$; otherwise, as nick points out in a comment, you are asking about convergence criteria for arbitrary sequences.

The only general convergence criterion I know of is Leibiz' criterion.

There is no comparison theorem like the one you ask about. The series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\quad\text{and}\quad\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}
$$
are both convergent by Leibniz criterion, but
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n-(-1)^n}
$$
converges, while
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n-(-1)^n}
$$
diverges.

Answer (score 0):

What about the Leibniz criterion http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test

Comment: You can use `[text](link)` to obtain e.g. [Leibniz criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test). Please [edit] your answer accordingly.